# Error when creating a diagram via jawira/db-draw php

Tags: php

I want to create a database diagram using php jawira/db-draw library (https://jawira.github.io/db-draw/index.html) for this.
Without using SQL queries everything works great, but when I want to use a query it displays an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Jawira\DbDraw\DbDraw::__construct(): Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Statement given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\diagram\index.php on line 18 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\diagram\vendor\jawira\db-draw\src\DbDraw.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\diagram\index.php(18): Jawira\DbDraw\DbDraw->__construct(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Statement)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\diagram\vendor\jawira\db-draw\src\DbDraw.php on line 26

Code below:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Jawira\DbDraw\{DbDraw, Theme};
use Jawira\PlantUmlClient\{Client, Format};

// a. Some logic to retrieve $connection (\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)
$connectionParams = ['url'    => 'mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/baza_testowa',
                     'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'];
$connection = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM czlowiek';
$stmt = $connection->query($sql);


//b. Generating PlantUML diagram
$dbDiagram = new DbDraw($stmt);
$puml      = $dbDiagram->generatePuml(DbDraw::MAXI, Theme::AMIGA);
file_put_contents('database.puml', $puml);

// c. Converting & saving png image
$client = new Client();
$png    = $client->generateImage($puml, Format::PNG);
file_put_contents('database.png', $png);
$url = $client->generateUrl($puml, Format::PNG);
echo "<img src='$url'>";
```

Probably on the line:

> $dbDiagram = new DbDraw($stmt);

There is a value written in parentheses. But the documentation is poor, so I don't know exactly what to put there. When I type $connection there it displays a diagram skipping the SQL query.

Please help.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `$dbDiagram = new DbDraw($connection);` as it appears to be after a connection and not a statement

Comment: @RiggsFolly As I mentioned above, when I type $connection in parentheses it displays a diagram of the entire database, not what is in the query.

Comment: From the docs, it seems you can only have a complete DB in the diagram, not bits

Comment: @RiggsFolly Doctrine/dbal allows to use SQL queries (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html). I just don't know how to use it in jawira and if it is even possible.

Comment: Well of course Doctrine allows you to use queries, we are not talking about Doctrine, I am not a jawira user but from the docs as I said above, it looks like you have to pass it a connection and it will do its own queries on that connection to get the schema from the database and uses that to build its diagram

Comment: "Probably on the line" - yeah, as the error message tells you: `DbDraw` needs a connection, not a statement. What makes you think it should be different?

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who wrote that library.

The library only works with a `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` instance (the `$connection` variable in your code).

This library is designed to generate a diagram for an entire database, not just a small part of it.

I am curious to know your use case; perhaps it could become a future feature.

BTW I also developed a Symfony Bundle that provides the same functionality [jawira/doctrine-diagram-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/jawira/doctrine-diagram-bundle)